# SQL Server 2005 Compressing result sets into one row of returned values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

SQL Server 2005

I'm  trying to  compress a result set to have one row of data per staff, my query is

```
SELECT  Staff +'- '+ CONVERT(CHAR(2),Service_Date, 110) AS Staff
,(SELECT COUNT (Procedure_) WHERE Procedure_ Like '90791%' ) AS '90791' 
,(SELECT COUNT (Procedure_) WHERE Procedure_ Like'90832%' )  AS '90832'
,(SELECT COUNT (Procedure_) WHERE Procedure_ Like'90834%' )  AS  '90834'
,(SELECT COUNT (Procedure_) WHERE Procedure_ Like'90837%' )  AS '90837' 
,(SELECT COUNT (Procedure_) WHERE Procedure_ Like '90847%')  AS '90847'

FROM dbo.Service_History 
WHERE Program='OPCC'
AND STATUS='Kept'
AND TYPE = 'Client'
AND Procedure_ IS NOT NULL 
AND Service_date BETWEEN DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0,GETDATE())-3, 0)  AND  GETDATE()


GROUP BY Staff +'- '+ CONVERT(CHAR(2),Service_Date, 110),Procedure_ 
ORDER BY Staff +'- '+ CONVERT(CHAR(2),Service_Date, 110),Procedure_

GROUP BY Staff +'- '+ CONVERT(CHAR(2),Service_Date, 110),Procedure_ 
ORDER BY Staff +'- '+ CONVERT(CHAR(2),Service_Date, 110),Procedure_
```

The result set is as follows: (one row per staff with one columns data returned, and one all NULL row).

```
Staff                       90791   90832   90834   90837   90847
Smith, Joe (568)- 04    15  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
Smith, Joe (568)- 04    NULL    NULL    2   NULL    NULL
Smith, Joe (568)- 04    NULL    NULL    NULL    1   NULL
Smith, Joe (568)- 04    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

I'd like to get the above results down to one row. Basically one row per staff per month that totals out the # of procedures performed.

Like ths:

```
Staff                       90791   90832   90834   90837   90847
Smith, Joe (568)- 04    15  NULL    2   1   NULL
```

My desired result can be achieved by importing the results to a temp table and then querying the temp table to get the results, but this is far from efficient and I am hoping there is a  better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the MAX() of each field.  ie:

```
ID  a     b     c     d
1   1     NULL  NULL  NULL
1   NULL  1     NULL  NULL
1   NULL  NULL  1     NULL

SELECT ID
     , MAX(a) AS a
     , MAX(b) AS b
     , MAX(c) AS c
     , MAX(d) as d
FROM Table
GROUP BY ID
```

Results in:

```
ID  a   b   c    d
1   1   1   1    NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
select staff + convert(char(2),service_date,110) staff,
count(case when procedure like '90791%' then staff end) '90791',
count(case when procedure like '90832%' then staff end) '90832',
count(case when procedure like '90834%' then staff end) '90834',
count(case when procedure like '90837%' then staff end) '90837',
count(case when procedure like '90847%' then staff end) '90847'

from service_history
where program='OPCC'
 ....
group by staff + convert(char(2),service_date,110)
```

That should do it!